# How to determine if a homogeneous integral equation has non-trivial solutions?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, integral-equations

The equation is

$f(p) = \int_{0}^{\Lambda} dk \; \mathcal{M}(k,p;E) \, f(k)$,

where the kernel $\mathcal{M}$ is

$\mathcal{M}(k,p;E) = \frac{2/ m\pi}{1 - \sqrt{E + 3p^2/4}} \frac{k}{p} \log\left( \frac{E + k^2 + p^2 + kp}{E + k^2 + p^2 - kp}\right)$.

The parameter $E > 1$, and $\Lambda \gg 1$ is some cutoff coming from the underlying quantum field theory.

(For those in the know, this the homogeneous Skorniakov-Ter-Martirosyan equation for quantum three-particle bound states, projected to the s-wave chennel.)

**Anyway, I don't even need to *solve* it.  All I want to know is, for a given parameter E, if the equation admits a solution $f(p) \neq 0$.**

This is my unenlightened way of thinking.  Recast the equation into

$0 = \int dk \, [\mathcal{M} - \delta(p-k)] f(k),$

discretize the integral:

$0 = \sum_{k} G_{p,k} f_k$,

and see if and when $\det \lvert G \rvert$ goes to zero.  I'm not even sure if it's working, because I haven't seen any zero so far!

Any comment and suggestion will be much appreciated.  Please lend a helping hand to this numerically illiterate physicist!

Comment: This is a classical question in functional analysis of integral equations. You will be better off asking this question on the Mathematics StackExchange forum.

Comment: All right then.  Do I delete this one and then re-post over there?

Comment: You can flag the question (use the grey link under the tags), choose "in need of moderator intervention" and write "please migrate to mathematics.se". (In fact, I just did that.)